# how to eleminate an option from a list and have an error message appear to prompt the user again

Tags: java, arrays

```
import java.util.*;
public class Yahtzee {
String choices[] = {"1 to roll a single dice","2 for a yahtzee score","3              
for a straight score","4 for a chance score"};
Dice dice3;
Dice dice2;
Dice dice1;
int CanYahtzee;
boolean canYahtzee;
boolean canStraight;
boolean canChance;
int numberOfRolls;
int total;
int turnCount;
int finalScore;
}

public void displayOptions() {
    if (numberOfRolls < 3){
        System.out.println(choices[0]);
    }
    if (canYahtzee){ 
        System.out.println(choices[1]);
    }
    if(canStraight){
        System.out.println(choices[2]);
    }
    if(canChance){
        System.out.println(choices[3]);
    }
}
public int promptUser(){
    boolean check = true;
    int choice = 0;
    while(check){
        System.out.println("Enter a choice"); 
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        choice = input.nextInt();

        if (choice == 2 ){ 
            noMoreYahtzee(); 
        }else if(choice ==3){ 
            noMoreStraight();
        }else if(choice == 4){ 
            noMoreChance(); 
        }
        if( (numberOfRolls < 3 && choice == 1) || (canYahtzee && choice ==2) || (canStraight && choice == 3) || (canChance && choice == 4)){
            check = false;
            return choice;
        }
    }
    return choice;
}
public void noMoreYahtzee(){
    canYahtzee = false;
}
public void noMoreStraight(){
    canStraight = false;
} 
public void noMoreChance() {
        canChance = false;
}
```

Sample of what it prints.

```
dice are: 2 2 4
1 to roll a single dice
2 for a yahtzee score
3 for a straight score
4 for a chance score
Enter a choice
1
What die would you like to roll1
dice are: 4 2 4
1 to roll a single dice
2 for a yahtzee score
3 for a straight score
4 for a chance score
Enter a choice
4
your current total is: 10
dice are: 5 5 5
1 to roll a single dice
2 for a yahtzee score
3 for a straight score
4 for a chance score
Enter a choice
2
your current total is: 50
dice are: 4 4 1
1 to roll a single dice
2 for a yahtzee score
3 for a straight score
4 for a chance score
Enter a choice
```

what it should do: if the player enters 2 3 or 4, the option to choose it should go away the second round and an error message should occur if the user trys to use an opted out choice. same example but the correct way.

```
dice are: 2 2 4
1 to roll a single dice
2 for a yahtzee score
3 for a straight score
4 for a chance score
Enter a choice
1
What die would you like to roll1
dice are: 4 2 4
1 to roll a single dice
2 for a yahtzee score
3 for a straight score
4 for a chance score
Enter a choice
4
your current total is: 10
dice are: 5 5 5
1 to roll a single dice
2 for a yahtzee score
3 for a straight score
Enter a choice
2
your current total is: 50
dice are: 4 4 1
1 to roll a single dice
3 for a straight score
Enter a choice
4
Error invalid option try again
3
```

ive tried using a couple different approaches to this issue but this is my current one that complies if anyone has an idea for my solution that can help i will be very greatfull.

Comment: Provide minimal information to the problem

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I would do:

In your promptUser() method, after the line

```
int choice = input.nextInt();
```

I would check what `choice` is, whether it is 2, 3, or 4.
From here, if it is 2, call `noMoreYahtzee()` 
or if it is 3, call`noMoreStraight()` or if it is 4, call `noMoreChance()`

Then, because you already wrote code in your displayChoices() method to check the value of the booleans, your code should work. Hope this helps.

Also, your `while(true)` loop is going to cause an infinite loop.
To fix this, I would add some things into your promptUser() method.

```
public int promptUser(){
    boolean check = true;
    int choice;
    while(check){
        System.out.println("Enter a choice"); 
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        choice = input.nextInt();
        if( (numberOfRolls < 3 && choice == 1) || (canYahtzee && choice ==2) || (canStraight && choice == 3) || (canChance && choice == 4)){
            check = false;
        }
    }
    return choice;
}
```

Comment: so are you saying do something like this

Comment: if (choice == 2){
            noMoreYahtzee();
            }else if(choice ==3){
            noMoreStraight();    
            }else if(choice == 4){
            noMoreChance();    
            }

Comment: i tired that but what happens is i get stuck in the while(true) loop and i get continually prompted to enter my choice

Comment: Yes, exactly that.

Comment: Oh Shoot I didnt even see the while(true) loop. The reason why you're getting stuck is because the while loop will stop running once it's parameter is false. In your case, while(true) is always true. Meaning it causes an infinite loop. Let me edit my original answer. Give me a sec

Comment: i think its because i have my conditions in my if statement that canYahtzee has to be true and choice == 2 and so on. and if it gets set to false it will never be able to return a choice

Comment: ok i just copy and pasted your code as is and im getting a error because it cannot return choice because it was initialized in the while loop

Comment: okay do int choice=1; or any number you like so it is initialized

Comment: ok so i got it to compile and the output is the exact same thing. should i still have the if statement that calls the methods?

Comment: Yes add that lmao

Comment: still doesnt work but i feel like its close to the solution